# mongodb, add the aggregate and still bring a field

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have a little problem, I want to make an appointment at the mongodb where he returns the total value of all the houses of a distinguished type, and also which street of these houses, at the moment I'm just making a query that brings me the total value of the houses of a certain type, how do I include one more field, that field must not be part of the sum or anything, it is just one more item that I need in my array, follow the code I have done so far, the which will it be necessary to include? I'm using mongo's native driver

```
var homesToRent = []
homesToRent = await mongodb(homesRent).aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
          _id: '$type',
          count: { $sum: '$value' }
        }
      }
])
```

the return should look something like this:

```
[
    {_id: 'master homes', count: 250, streets: ['street one',' street two', 'street nice'] },
    {_id: 'top homes', count: 450, streets: ['another street', 'simple street']}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do something like that:

```
var homesToRent = []
homesToRent = await mongodb(homesRent).aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
          _id: '$type',
          count: { $sum: '$value' },
          streets: { $addToSet: '$street' }
        }
      }
])
```